# "cannot import name bayesflow" error for Tensorflow 1.2.1 version

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I installed latest tensorflow version as:

```
sudo pip2 install tensorflow
```

But while import layers as

```
from tensorflow.contrib import layers
```

I get an error:

```
cannot import name bayesflow
```

What am I missing?
I am using Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Hey. Did you resolve this issue? I run into just the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was in the similar position as you: `tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)` was generating the same error. After a lot of searching and trying I found that I should update `dask`. So

```
pip install --upgrade dask
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still experience this problem, the best is to upgrade tensorflow  with `sudo pip install --upgrade tensorflow` or even uninstall it `sudo pip uninstall tensorflow` and reinstall it `sudo pip install tensorflow`.

When it's done you have to close the ipython or any shell you are using (this is important)